# How to achieve Long click in Uiautomator

Tags: android, button, click, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I am trying to write a code to capture pictures in burst mode.This requires long click (for about a minute)on the Capture button.How to achieve this?

```
UiObject CameraButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Capture"));
        CameraButton.longClick();
```

longclick() : how much time it will hold the button?Is it possible to perform a long click with a time stamp.

Answer (score 4):

Use **swipe (int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int steps)** to perform long click for a time you wish. The last parameter **steps** determines the time. [For a 100 steps, the swipe will take about 1/2 second to complete.](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#swipe%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) The greater the value of steps, the longer the duration of click and release.

```
UiObject CameraButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Capture"));
Rect CameraButton_rect = CameraButton.getBounds();
getUiDevice().swipe(CameraButton_rect.centerX(), CameraButton_rect.centerY(), CameraButton_rect.centerX(), CameraButton_rect.centerY(), 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UIAutomator2, from version v18:2.1.3 onwards - 
This long click handling is simplified with a click with wait duration.

```
 /** Performs a click on this object that lasts for {duration} milliseconds. */
    public void click(long duration)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [drag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiObject.html#dragTo%28android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject,%20int%29) the object to itself:

```
UiObject CameraButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Capture"));
CameraButton.dragTo(CameraButton, 10);
```

Chose the steps acording to the time you want it to take.

Answer (score 0):

For UIautomator 2.0 you shoud try like this:

```
BySelector selector = By.res("resourceID");
UiObject2 obj = mDevice.findObject(selector);
Point pot = obj.getVisibleCenter();
mDevice.swipe(pot.x, pot.y, pot.x, pot.y, 200);
```